# If $|a_{n+1} - 2a_n| = 2$ and $|a_n| \leq 2$ and $a_1$ is rational, then it is as periodic sequence.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

> If $|a_{n+1} - 2a_n| = 2$ and $|a_n| \leq 2$ and $a_1$ is rational, then it is as periodic sequence.

Periodic sequence means that there exists $p\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $a_n = a_{n+p}$ for all values of $n.$

I have no idea how to start at all.

Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: I think your definition of periodicity has a typo. Surely you mean $a_p = a_{m+p}$?

Comment: @user754697 I edited my post.

Comment: Also, $a_n = (-1)^n \frac{2}{3}$ is a counterexample to eventual constancy.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг I edited my definition of periodic. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $a_1$ is rational, we know that $qa_1 = p$ for some integers $p,q$.

Now, note that either $a_{n+1} = 2a_n - 2$ if $a_n > 0$, and $a_{n+1} = 2 + 2a_n$ otherwise.

Using this, one sees by induction that $qa_{n}$ is an integer for all $n$. However, because $|a_n| \leq 2$ , we have $|qa_n| \leq 2q$ for all $n$.

Therefore, the sequence $a_n$ takes values only in the set $\{\frac kq : -2q \leq k \leq 2q\}$. By the pigeonhole principle, $a_i = a_j$ for some $i<j$ finite (Take $a_1,...,a_{2q+2}$).

Now, once this happens, noting that $a_n \to a_{n+1}$ is an injective function (the inverse is clear from my restatement of the mapping above) tells you that the sequence is periodic, because $a_i = a_j$ implies $a_{k} = a_l $ for all $k,l$ differing by $j-i$. (For $k < i$, use injectivity. For $k>i$, repeatedly apply the recurrence).

EDIT :Suppose $a_1 \neq 0$. Then, if $|a_1| < 2$ we can use the recurrence to conclude that $|a_n | < 2$ for all $n$. In this case, injectivity is obtained. If that $a_1 = \pm 2$. Then, the sequence looks like $2,-2,2,-2,...$ or the negative of each term. The only problem occurs when some $a_n = 0$, in which case the sequence looks like $0,2,-2,2,-2,...$ or its negative after that. Either way, the sequence is eventually periodic.

Comment: There's a little more to do here. Note that the sequences $0, 2, 2, 2, \ldots$ and $0, -2, -2, -2, \ldots$ show that the sequences are not necessarily periodic, and that the map $a_n \to a_{n+1}$ is not injective.

Comment: I will provide an edit.

Comment: Sorry to nitpick you again, but the problem does make sense with allowing $a_n = 0$. The problem doesn't ever claim that its recursively defining a sequence, just asks us to consider a sequence satisfying certain conditions. As we've seen, there certainly are sequences satisfying this condition with $a_n = 0$ for some $n$.

Comment: You are right! But would it be right to say that such a sequence is at least eventually periodic i.e. there exists $N$ such that the subsequence $a_N,a_{N+1},...$ is periodic? Only injectivity fails, therefore this should work out.

Comment: I think it is right to say this, though I haven't worked out the details. I think $0$ can occur only once in the sequence (depending, I think, on the number of factors of $2$ in the denominator of $a_1$), after which the sequence repeats, and your logic proves eventual periodicity.

Comment: Actually, now that I think about it, as soon as $0$ occurs, then the sequence becomes constantly $\pm 2$, so injectivity eventually holds, and we do get eventual periodicity.